# Is it possible to check the onmouseout event of element's parent if onmouseout event occurs on this element?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, event-handling

Let me explain this scenario:
I have a JSP having a table whose source code is not available to me.
Inside the table's `<TD>` tag, however I can dynamically insert a anchor tag using Java codes:

```
String html =
 "<a href=\"javascript:showReleaseVersionsPopUp('" + currentRow.getComponentSeq() + "'); \" class=\"windowletIcon\">" +
                "<img src=\"./images/information-button.png\" width='25' height='20' id='img_"+currentRow.getComponentSeq()+"' " +
                        />" +
 "</a>";
return html;
```

Now what I want is, if a mouse enter's this Anchor tag, it goes to Javascript `showReleaseVersionsPopUp()` and shows a hidden DIV, however on mouseout event on this Anchor tag, I don't want it to go to Javascript `hideReleaseVersionsPopUp()` and hide the DIV. I rather want that Javascript `hideReleaseVersionsPopUp()` should be called on mouseout event on the Parent `<TD>` tag of this Anchor tag.

I believe to do this first I will need set a mouseout event handler on the Anchor tag and stop the event from bubbling and then set the event handler on it's parent `<TD>` tag.

However, to reiterate here, I don't have access to the JSP code and the `<TABLE>` code, so all I can do is through the Java code mentioned above.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a event handler to the onmouseout event of the parent node.

```
var el = document.getElementById('idOfAnchor').parentNode;

if (el.addEventListener) {

  el.addEventListener('mouseout', hideReleaseVersionsPopUp ); 

} else if (el.attachEvent)  { // for IE8 and previous versions

  el.attachEvent('mouseout', hideReleaseVersionsPopUp );

}
```

Comment: Use `addEventListener` instead of hard-wiring the events.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks for pointing that out. Only one way to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `myElement.parentNode` to get the parent element of `myElement`. You can then do anything with that parent element that you'd want. DOM manipulation, event listeners, you name it.

So just don't add a `mouseout` event listener on the Anchor, but on the Anchor's parent, instead.